# Storybook - How to import a component from a external project using styled-components (React + TS)?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, storybook

I am trying to import a component from an external project into my storybook. I imported it, for example, a custom Button, but the style is not being rendered, it shows only the default html button style and not my styled-component.

I also tried importing it in .storybook/preview.js like the other scss files and bootstrap library, but still, the styled-components style is not being rendered.

```
import Button from "..filelocation"
```

Answer (score 1):

For storybook you can make a global (storybook folder) css style by making a `.storybook/preview-head.html` file and adding your css there via css. source: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/styling-and-css

However you can also just add a styles.css inside your storybook component and call it with `import './styles.css';`

Comment: Hi,
Css and scss are not the problem I imported them and they work fine. But how do you import the style of styled-components? For example I import a button styled-component, but it has no style as it should have. For example I set border-color: red, and it shows me just plain html - basic button.

Comment: maybe this config will help https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/configure/webpack#extending-storybooks-webpack-config, its what im using but postcss instead of sass-loader.

try   
  
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],

Comment: hm, I actually have the same in my main.js file (inside of .storybook), but still, the style is not being rendered. I tried creating styled-components inside of the storybook project and they get rendered correctly, but when I import them from a different project it does not work. I also tried to import the theme provider from the other project and to provide the global theme to the storybook but still nothing. Thanks